# How to match one or two consecutive (and get them into groups) numbers in this string: -4-45- or -15-25-03-

Tags: regex

Im new to regex. Im trying to understand how it works. But cant seem to get to match single or multiple digits on an string and get them as groups, I can only get it to match a single digit.

Im trying to get it to work in this two strings: *-4-45-*  OR *-15-25-03-*

Im testing it using this online tool: https://regex101.com/

I have tried to use:

```
\-([0-9]*?)\-
```

But it only gets the first four as a match.

```
\-([0-9]{0,4})\-
```

Doesnt get any match, i tougth the brackets where to specify a length.

```
\-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\-
```

Same as the first one, only works with the first number, I think I dont understand how the "OR" works.

Here is an screenshoot with some results:
https://prnt.sc/napafa

**Expected Results: *-4-45-***

Group 1: 4

Group 2: 45

**and for the second string: *-15-25-03-***

Group 1: 15

Group 2: 25

Group 3: 03

Hope you can help me, i have been watching some tutorials, and i get it to work with text, but I think im missing something with numbers.

Comment: You can only have as many groups in the output as there are capturing groups in the pattern. Use `-\K\d+(?![^-])` / `(?<![^-])\d+(?![^-])` to match all numbers in between hyphens/ start/end of string.

Comment: You can use `(?<=-)(\d+)(?=-)`. It's because you're matching the end `-`, which is preventing the next match from matching the starting `-`. Changing this to lookbehinds and lookaheads prevents this from happening as it's simply checking to make sure that the `-` character exists there without consuming it. In terms of quantifiers, `+` can be used to indicate one or more

Comment: You can match one or more digits with `[0-9]+` or `\d+`, you could get multiple matches using the `g` flag, but to get multiple groups within a single match you will need to be explicit in your pattern.

Comment: @ctwheels Oh I see the problem now, those lookahead and lookbehind makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You only have one set of parenthesis, that's one Group.